# Azure Web App created with stack 3.1 but --version shows 2.2

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-appservice

I created a Azure Web App to deploy a asp.net core 3.1 project on it. I have selected the 3.1 stack but when I SSH into the web app service and type dotnet --version, it shows 2.2 rather than 3.1 Why is that the case and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were running the command on the docker host instance and not the actual app service.

You can go to the **General settingd** of *Configuration* under **Settings** to check Stacking settings of your app.
[image]

You can run `dotnet --list-runtimes` using the **SSH** tool under **Development Tools** in your Web App blade to view 3.1 running on your app.

[image]

See [this document](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/04/16/Announcing-.NET-Core-3.1-LTS-Generally-Available-on-App-Service.html) for more information.

Comment: But should the docker host instance also have 3.1? If so, why it's on 2.2?

Comment: I checked and found that .NET Core 3.1 sdk folder exists under `opt/dotnet/sdks`. Probably it is not added to the PATH variable, so the the command doesnot work.